# Xcode Build Fails on Cocoapods Copy Resources

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, gpuimage

I recently added GPUImage to my podfile in Xcode, as follows:

```
pod 'GPUImage', '~> 0.1.4'
```

I don't think the problem I'm having is GPUImage specific, but rather has to do with the fact that GPUImage is the only pod I've added that includes extra resources.

My build keeps failing with "Shell Script Invocation Error, exit code 23".

```
./Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup.png
./Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_amatorka.png
./Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_miss_etikate.png
./Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_soft_elegance_1.png
./Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_soft_elegance_2.png
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup.png" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_amatorka.png" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_miss_etikate.png" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_soft_elegance_1.png" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup_soft_elegance_2.png" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done
sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23
```

I think it's a problem with some sort of build path/pod configuration, but I tried for quite a while to fix it myself and am ready to ask for help...  The real annoyance is that I'm not even using those resources!  If I go into my Pods-resources.sh file and manually comment out all the "install_resource" lines, everything builds just fine and my project works fine.  Of course, that is only a temporary/fragile solution, I'd like to just fix the issue at the source.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Some things I've tried:

- Xcode clean
- Deletion of derived data
- Removing GPUImage pod, then
  installing again

Comment: Did you get this to work?  What version of CP are you using?  I'm having same error.  I'm on 0.36.0.beta.2 and the exact same project with 0.36.0.beta.1 works nicely.

Comment: I did not get this to work and temporarily gave up on it.  My "solution" was to comment out all of GPUImage's install_resource lines in the Pods-resources.sh file.  This was sufficient for us because we have no use for any of those pngs that GPUImage includes.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm seeing the problem on a different pod than GPUImage, but will look into the same approach temporarily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problem with cocoapods beta (`--pre`). Reinstall stable version:

```
sudo gem uninstall --all cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: That worked well for me.  I was using 0.36.0-beta1 successfully, the issue started when moving to 0.36.0-beta2, and reverting to 0.35.0 works.  Will file a bug in the cocoapods tracker.

Comment: Don't forget to reinstall the pod after that too

Answer (score 0):

Well the files [seem](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/framework/Resources) to be in the repository so maybe you should check inside your local Pods directory.

Also you could try to delete the directory and `pod install` again.

Comment: Tried deleting the pods folder/workspace file and doing a complete reinstall, but didn't work; got the same error.

Comment: Do the files exist at the specified paths? (`./Pods/GPUImage/framework/Resources/lookup.png`, etc.)

Comment: Yes, all the files exist at those paths.

Comment: Well clearly they can't be found by the script. Either `PODS_ROOT`, build directory or another variable is not correctly set. TO verify try adding the Pod to a new project and it should work.

Comment: I can indeed get GPU image to work in a new project... My PODS_ROOT is set to ./Pods in my .xcodeproj file.  It's only the resource files that aren't copying.  When commented out, GPUImage and my other pods work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was something different than Cfr's answer.  I had an old Pod file I removed from the Podfile, but somehow, it was still on the Schemes.  I removed it from the Managed schemes and it worked.